# how to index a numpy array using another numpy array with different number of dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of shape (B, N, 3) and an array of indexes with shape (B, M) with M<N
I want to get, for each item in B, M elements at the indexes indicated by the array of indexes, getting an array of shape (B, M, 3)

What I have tried with no success

```
array[indexes]

array[indexes.to_list()]
```

I am sure there is a fancy way of doing this but I haven't found it. Any advice?

Comment: Can you show example input arrays and expected output?

Comment: so you want to index the `N` dimension?

Comment: Try `array[ np.arange(B)[:,None], indexes, :]`.  The idea is to make (B,1) index array that `broadcasts` with the (B,M) one.